# Escape sequence in python

Tags: python, unicode, hex

What is the difference between `\x` and `\u` escape sequences in python? (Apart from the fact that `\x` uses the syntax `\xXX` and `\u` uses `\uXXXX`). `print('\xa5')` gives the output as `'¥'` in script mode and so does `print('\u00a5')`, so how is one different from the other, apart from the syntax used?

Comment: The answer to this question does not help me directly with my problem, however the link provided in the answer [link](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) was indeed very helpful, thank you @ChrisStillwell for pointing out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important difference is that `\uXXXX` accepts 4 hexadecimal digits and is therefore suitable for higher numbers (and therefore can be used to refer to special characters that are not in ASCII or your current code page). It can therefore only be used in unicode strings:

```
u'\u0123'
```

The older `\xXX` can be used in both unicode strings and `str` strings, but only for code points up to 255:

```
u'\u0123\x20'
'\x20'
```